# how to use Sendbird chat SDK with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chat, sendbird

I have vue.js application and I have a requirement to integrate sendbird one to one chat in that application. Is it possible and anyone have done it?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this library isn't designed to work with other frameworks such as Vue or Angular. see docs here: https://sendbird.com/docs/uikit/v1/react/quickstart/send-first-message